# Image diffing in iOS to obtain % difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, image, jailbreak

I am creating a comprehensive filtering tweak for Instagram's iOS app to remove unwanted posts. I am trying to add a feature to store all viewed thumbnails and use image diffing to determine whether any new thumbnails are reposts.

What is the most efficient way to obtain a % difference between two images in iOS? Since this is a tweak, I would like to avoid the use of third-party libraries, if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: you don't know how to do it, but you don't want to use someone else's library that does it. So what exactly are you looking for? What you'll probably end up with is some answer with a code snippet that you'll copy. That's like the shittiest form of code re-use ever. It wouldn't have thousands of users to have tested/vet it rigorously, you won't get automatic updates when a new version is made, and you just bloat your code base

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica A native code snippet would be ideal, as I would prefer for the tweak download to be as small as possible (as people often download things on-the-fly), and I wouldn't receive automatic updates anyway. Of course, if it can't be done without a library then I won't complain about using one, but if it is feasible to do without one then I'd prefer doing that.

Comment: "as I would prefer for the tweak download to be as small as possible" that sounds like a job for a compiler, not a person 

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica in which case, how could the size of the download be minimised?

Comment: Do you even have a library in mind that's too big? You're optimizing to fix a problem that doesn't exist yet

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I've heard that OpenCV has the functionality, but afaik the lib is pretty large.

Comment: I would advise you to make something that works, and worry about trimming fat later. Right now you're worrying about solving a hypothetical problem of a solution to a problem you can't otherwise solve, it doens't make sense

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Well, I know it's possible with OpenCV, but the package constitutes 70 MB (!!), which is behemothic, even compared to theme debs. It would push my deb to > 100 MB, which is to be avoided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211580/discussion-between-alexander-reinstate-monica-and-jacobcxdev).